# Adding a .gitlab-ci.yml file doesn't activate CI

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a number of repositories on my local gitlab installation.  I am migrating from Jenkins to gitlab for CI, and switched my first repo over no problem.  The second repo didn't activate the CI when I added the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.  Specifically, the `Pipelines` link doesn't show up in the project page.

Has anyone had this problem?  Any ideas of how to force the CI to activate and recognize the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to this.  In the project settings (Gear Icon -> Edit Project), be sure that `Builds` is not set to `Disabled`

Comment: For Gitlab-CE version 9.0.5 go to your Project then Settings->General. In the section "Sharing & Permissions" make sure that "Repository -> Pipelines" is not set to disabled.

Comment: It is enabled but still no CI triggered. I have other repositories working fine, what the hell ???

Comment: Neveeermind. I had defined `only: master` inside the new branch `ci`. Therefore, nothing to run. :D

Answer (score 3):

For my case, the committed .gitlab-ci.yml didn't working, after deleting and creating a new one through gitlab web portal in repository directly, it works.

I notice that file icon is different. [Working .gitlab-ci.yml icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0lQV.png)